# Volume of the sound recording for Android

Tags: android, audio-recording, volume

I recording audio using AudioRecorder. How can I dynamically get the recording sound volume or intensity of sound? I want to display a ProgressBar displaying the intensity of sound received in microphone.

Comment: With MediaRecorder: MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();

Answer (score 1):

Look at this project [NoiseAlert](http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/wiki/NoiseAlert)
It uses MediaRecorder, not AudioRecorder.
But maybe it will help. Very similar to what you need.